# Custom Visual C++ CRL assembly not found

Tags: c#, c++, .net, exception, .net-assembly

I have a `C#` `WPF` application that uses a Visual `C++` CRL assembly. Both project have as target framework `.NET 4.0`. When I run the program on the computer with Visual Studio where I developed the project, as well as on my personal pc I do not have any kind of problem. But it can happen that in some computers, when the application calls the method where I call a method defined in the assembly, I get an unhandled exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Why do I get this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What dependencies does your c++ dll have ?

Comment: @auburg mscorlib System.Data System System.Xml, but even removing System.Data and System.Xml the problem remains

Comment: It has more.  You write a C++/CLI assembly to wrap native C++ code.  So at a minimum you have a dependency on the C runtime library.  Like msvcr120.dll and perhaps msvcp120.dll assuming you use VS2013 (don't make us guess).  And perhaps that C++ code as well if it lives in its own DLL.  Or uses DLLs itself.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor if you have no idea.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you will need to install the related [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145). Sorry mixed it up with the sdk.

Comment: In this case how should I modify the Visual Studio project properties in order to fix the problem?

Comment: The SDK is only ever required on a dev machine, never the user's machine.

Comment: You are right - I meant the Visual C++ Redistributable .